# Linear regression of time series over multiple columns

Tags: r, time-series, regression, multiple-columns, zoo

I have the following problem. I want to compute the regression of an annual time series in matrix form. In total, I have 56 time series I extracted from gridpoints of an area I want to examine, so that I've got 56 values per year. I've plotted all values as points in a figure. Now I want to add a regression line to this figure, which contains all data.

My goal is to compute the regression for the whole matrix.

```
library(zoo)

pdf(file="/home/user/name.pdf", pointsize=20, onefile = FALSE, width=18, height=11, paper = "special")
plot(mat.zoo[,1], pch=20, type="p", ylim=c(8,max(mat.zoo)),
     yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", lwd = 1.5, main = "Some title", 
     ylab = "ylabtext", xlab ="", col = "black")

tt <- time(mat.zoo)
ix <- seq(1, length(tt), by=1) #every year a tick
labs <- format(tt[ix])
axis(side = 1, at = tt[ix], labels = labs,  tcl = -0.7, cex.axis = 1)

for (i in 2:ncol(mat.zoo)) {  
  #plot every column
  points(mat.zoo[,i], pch=20, lwd = 1.5)
}

## create ticks at every first y value 
axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, max(mat.zoo), by = 1), labels = FALSE)
iy <- seq(0, max(mat.zoo), 2)
axis(side = 2, at = iy, cex.axis = 1)

#this line doesn't work
abline( lm(mat.zoo ~ tt), col="light blue", lwd=3 )

dev.off()
```

figure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj31Y.png

Some sample data, if I use dput()

```
structure(c(14.6108611110572, 15.0943707315979, 16.4246753285039, 
15.4777258564571, 15.3910647660091, 14.9576052728563, 14.577379912167, 
15.6818364395762, 15.3935454316438, 14.6986382632628, 14.9616178291156, 
14.6208764396762, 17.4073263088521, 16.3932907105236, 16.4711871055354, 
15.7165524844793, 15.910687798697, 15.2800531253961, 16.2585353059321, 
14.9642915613775, 15.5682258772038, 15.7581733353644, 16.3600126905042, 
15.9906231843285, 16.4740591781654, 16.6207709477207, 16.7107736486755, 
15.3495937400046, 15.081738134456, 17.8213361743775, 17.0073514277019, 
16.0639354869614, 15.7564229038361, 16.4711872385234, 16.1474456418556, 
16.1012429675788, 14.935862417968, 14.649232718741, 14.7248073786802, 
16.3713171174875, 16.5047383689279, 15.6553509485205, 15.8069612127912, 
15.0880755914505, 15.9605131388024, 15.1647608142339, 15.0206531342878, 
15.8533914806642, 16.1936611693424, 14.4341552680467, 15.0030002589802, 
16.2373036559464, 15.4563912060316, 15.7540478676699, 14.4544119112367, 
14.1481450642128, 15.8808048538232, 15.3109864936677, 14.6184823877101, 
14.759740997088, 14.4554473653311, 17.1869089559961, 16.032779242263, 
15.9154018617995, 15.7003191635601, 16.1782858717824, 15.005330870126, 
16.1074524252519, 15.387333324397, 15.4238444378858, 15.7384875972114, 
16.3306448173221, 15.8050630623362, 16.5357139417134, 15.7318155157117, 
16.6027108391727, 15.3521994865507, 14.6028494060288, 17.0695642066462, 
16.5601941440799, 16.0704699986853, 15.9527367313925, 15.8492898967367, 
15.8094909404139, 15.9223122951851, 14.7427484210632, 14.3087395573591, 
14.9164340340289, 16.5109060631933, 16.1756705822203, 15.6869363317253, 
15.302941446409, 14.7871569748782, 16.2405108282472, 14.9030204259848, 
15.1076128392841, 15.7835364136346, 16.2406871099921, 13.9434587358454, 
14.8761562136977, 16.5604955686145, 15.3055531556642, 15.528200122034, 
14.3683664247369, 14.8660671257497, 16.2483828855783, 15.5912163679296, 
14.5206758668367, 15.0572249827849, 14.2126710362867, 16.7430589790551, 
15.913830135814, 15.5309377608968, 15.4301657033962, 16.1024796689616, 
14.9412190564665, 15.5415580911515, 15.6185795702858, 15.246965832492, 
15.5331896889331, 16.0527261022428, 16.2496153707101, 16.1013003488606, 
15.4012992267683, 16.6433171425044, 15.3443805149379, 15.0832591147848, 
17.2409394600713, 16.3670395392329, 15.8028463074112, 16.230362038712, 
15.8533914346074, 16.0962730847646, 15.4780493166121, 14.7644838005869, 
14.0160611132642, 14.7363498686371, 16.5339052116905, 16.1142787861115, 
15.1343982378726, 15.0479243093561, 14.8394739356758, 16.2015436792666, 
14.8852279610404, 15.171354759099, 15.8823805835669, 16.082598536468, 
13.6882801770178, 15.1822273858009, 16.7314060285488, 15.1822255101789, 
15.6470428935629, 14.6219009419668, 14.5344414346855, 17.0856674074961, 
15.6276761713817, 14.9656277726849, 15.0416098763217, 14.8660691394921, 
16.8350823196938, 15.7276830387531, 15.6464050524098, 15.7889210440969, 
15.8260661780512, 15.0685110014866, 15.5003231376182, 15.1818971179834, 
15.2523764253926, 15.2397513974873, 16.4076206985996, 16.2609962527472, 
15.9563455712026, 14.6758308266033, 15.9928106586864, 15.3388404382473, 
15.3352069271315, 17.491711796634, 16.3110401122382, 15.6722694212894, 
16.0979740581832, 15.9314161173117, 15.5309368794019, 15.5425227514293, 
14.8653903137068, 14.3680198631293, 14.6030824713595, 16.7764724794758, 
15.7590262768357, 14.9562687841841, 14.7258278360439, 15.00733114536, 
16.1086825085102, 14.8246425174662, 15.6697167018262, 15.5235314139726, 
15.810753562246), .Dim = c(49L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"367", "732", "1097", "1462", "1828", "2193", "2558", "2923", 
"3289", "3654", "4019", "4384", "4750", "5115", "5480", "5845", 
"6211", "6576", "6941", "7306", "7672", "8037", "8402", "8767", 
"9133", "9498", "9863", "10228", "10594", "10959", "11324", "11689", 
"12055", "12420", "12785", "13150", "13516", "13881", "14246", 
"14611", "14977", "15342", "15707", "16072", "16438", "16803", 
"17168", "17533"), c("GB.1", "GB.2", "GB.3", "GB.4")), index = c(1960, 
1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 
1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 
1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008), class = "zoo")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your `lm` statement to

```
lm(as.vector(mat.zoo) ~ rep(tt, length.out = length(mat.zoo)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It is my goal to compute the regression for the whole matrix (all values). Sorry, if it wasn't clear in the beginning.

Comment: If I would compute the regression for every column separately, it would work with your line of code. Is there the possibility to put everything in one vector, where I have first the 56 values for 1960, after that  the 56 values for 1961 and so on? Can I transform my matrix into a vector like that?

Comment: The following line does it, but i have to create a timestamp for the new vector:                                                     as.vector(t(mat.zoo))

Comment: tt.vec <- rep(1960:2008, each = ncol(mat.zoo))
abline( lm(zoo(as.vector(t(TS.MW.GB.quan50.zoo)),tt.vec) ~ tt.vec), col="red", lwd=3 )

Comment: The code above does not work unfortunately. I get the following error: In zoo(rval[i], index(x)[i]) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

Comment: Thank you really much. Could you tell me, how rep(tt, length.out = length(mat.zoo)) matches the data, they belong to? as.vector transforms column after column in one vector, so that the individual timestamps  match with the data, they belong to, to compute the linear regression in the end, am I right?

Comment: Glad it worked :) Yes this is the reason, the associated time stamps are just obtained by recycling `tt` as many times as there are columns in `mat.zoo`. You could write `rep(tt, ncol(mat.zoo))` and it would be the same.